# Accessing webservice of home network from the internet

Tags: android, python, web-services, http, authentication

In my home network I use a device with web services. Now I want to access this service from the internet. As I have no static IP (and don't want one) my idea was to use/develop two "forwarders". One on a server (e.g. Google App Engine) and one on my local NAS (with Python).

Does anyone know applications / frameworks to do this easily or even knows a better solution for my problem?

Of course the solution should also include some kind of authentication. As I use my own developed android app as endpoint I'm able to customize the communication.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you just want to run a home based web server without static IP. If you have a linux server, you can try this:

Use the apache webserver installed by default and set up a test page. The page is dropped into your webservers public directory. Now, how to resolve your IP...lets say it is...25.24.4.166 and you want it to have a host.name.com to bind to. Go to http://www.no-ip.com/index.php and sign up. You can get a site from noip that is like yourname.theirdomain.com/.net/.info. They have cool names like sytes.net and servebeer.org...even workisboring.com

You'll be able to choose your own top level name...for instance, Ithink.dnsiskinky.com could be your new domain name. Next download a client from the download tab: https://www.no-ip.com/downloads.php

The linux client is a tar.gz source and is simple to install. Just follow the instructions. Now you own yoursite.theirsite.com and your IP will ALWAYS update (as long as noip.com is up) each time you log on/sign on/beam up or whatever it is you do.

It isn't too much trouble to generalize this technique for dynamic web services. Sorry about the authentication, it's a whole other story as I haven't thought about it enough. May be you can send a request header hash or something like that (like for ex. what Amazon does in s3 and other related services for authentication).

Comment: To be clear, user is suggesting you use dynamic dns, which gives you a consistent hostname, despite having a dynamic ip. no-ip is one of many services for this (google it). Expect that you can get it for free. As for client, the best bet is to let your router update your ip automatically. Many routers have built-in support for various dyndns services, as do openwrt and dd-wrt firmware.